# Port binding conflicts with "switch user" on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fast-user-switching

We are using the switch user function within Windows 7 under an active directory network.

We have one application in particular that gives us an error:

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
>   is normally permitted.
>
> bind Port 10001

Are there any other ports that can only be used at one time that might have an adverse effect on the other user? We try to mentor our users to use the log off function instead of switch user, but that doesn't always happen.

As an alternative, is it possible to disable the 'switch user' button on our machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is probably due to the program being unable to open the same port that the first instance of the program has already opened. Switching profiles will not free up the ports already opened by programs/services on the first profile.

I can't think of a good, compelling reason to have this feature enabled in an AD environment. You can disable Fast User Switching via GPO under *Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, System, Logon*. `Enable` the `Hide entry points for Fast User Switching` setting.